# Flask form validation design

Tags: python, forms, validation, flask

I'm not new to programming but I am new to Python and Flask.  I have a design question regarding form validation.

I have a registration form that captures the user information as well as the company they belong to.  The form then validates whether the email is already in use but I want to also validate whether or not the company has been signed up before.  I don't want the same company to sign up more than once.

Trying to match solely on company name will likely cause issues because users don't necessarily spell things the same (ie: adding or omitting punctuation).  My thought is to validate on the first X number of characters in the company name, the street address number, and zip code.  If there is a match, the user isn't allowed to sign up and they will have to call in (or some other process to be determined).

Ok, the real question... Is it a better to add the validation to the WTF form?  Or add a helper function in the model?  I'm validating three fields and didn't know which was best practice.

EDIT - I'm really asking if I have to validate on more than one field, do I add it to the Form or with a helper function in the model?

Thanks for your assistance.

Jimmy

Comment: Why not homogenize the data so that the user cannot make the mistakes you mention? I think at least the obvious ones should be covered, like `A company, a company, company, the company`. I'd just convert all of those to `company` before saving to the database..

Comment: That might work. I'll give it more thought but at first glance, I think I'd still have to do that validation because it's quite possible to have companies with the same name in multiple cities/states.

Answer (score 1):

Validating using WTForms is likely better in this case. It will be easier to send an error message to the user.

In WTForms, it is easy to add a [custom validator](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/validators.html):

```
class MyForm(Form):
company = TextField('Company', [Required()])

def validate_company(form, field):
    if len(field.data) > 50:
        raise ValidationError('Name must be less than 50 characters')
```

In your case, however, this will not work because you want to do multiple fields. WTForms to the rescue! You can validate all of your company fields through a [field enclosure](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#field-enclosures). This will allow you to treat "company info" as one field and validate over each of them.

```
class CompanyForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Company name', [validators.required()])
    address    = StringField('Address', [validators.required()])

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    first_name   = StringField()
    last_name    = StringField()
    company = FormField(CompanyForm, [your_custom_validation])
```

You can also add uniqueness requirements to your DB model. Not sure what your database is, but MongoDB provides a `unique_with` requirement. But that won't do any validation, it will just throw an error if you try to create non-unique db entries.